# How to find aliases in emacs

Tags: emacs, alias

I want to check if there is a default\ existing aliasing for a function (in this case:`x-clipboard-yank`, but the question is general).
Is there an emacs function that displays active aliases I can use to figure it up?
The expected behavior is like the shell `alias` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the value of `(symbol-function 'THE-FUNCTION)`.  If the value is a symbol then `THE-FUNCTION` is an alias.

However, if the value is not a symbol `THE-FUNCTION` might nevertheless have been defined using `defalias` (or `fset`). In that case, `THE-FUNCTION` was aliased not to another function's symbol but to a function definition (e.g. the current function definition of some symbol, instead of the symbol itself) or to a variable definition (e.g. the value of a keymap variable).

You probably do not care about this case anyway - you probably do not even think of it as an alias.  So testing whether the `symbol-function` value is a non-`nil` symbol is probably sufficient.  (A value of `nil` means the there is neither a function alias nor any other function definition for the given symbol.)

So for example:

```
(defun aliased-p (fn)
  "Return non-nil if function FN is aliased to a function symbol."
  (let ((val  (symbol-function fn)))
    (and val                            ; `nil' means not aliased
         (symbolp val))))
```

---

In response to the question in your comment: Here is a command version of the function:

```
(defun aliased-p (fn &optional msgp)
  "Prompt for a function name and say whether it is an alias.
Return non-nil if the function is aliased."
  (interactive "aFunction: \np")
  (let* ((val  (symbol-function fn))
         (ret  (and val  (symbolp val))))
    (when msgp (message "`%s' %s an alias" fn (if ret "IS" "is NOT")))
    ret))
```

---

To be clear about the non-symbol case - If the code does this:

```
(defalias 'foo (symbol-function 'bar))
```

then `foo` is aliased to the current function definition of `bar`.  If the definition of `bar` is subsequently changed, that will have no effect on the definition of `foo`.  `foo`'s definition is a snapshot of `bar`'s definition at the time of the `defalias`ing.

But if the code does this:

```
(defalias 'foo 'bar)
```

then `foo` is aliased to the symbol `bar`. `foo`'s function definition is the symbol `bar`: `(symbol-function 'foo)` = `bar`.  So if `bar`'s function definition gets changed then `foo`'s definition follows accordingly.

Comment: How am I suppose to check the value of the function symbol-function? I'll be able to check your  answer only tomorrow, sorry for the delay.

Comment: You don't check the value of function `symbol-function`. You use `symbol-function` to check the function value of some function you want to know about. If `(symbol-function 'toto)` returns a symbol `titi` then function `toto` is an alias for function `titi`. If it returns something other than a (non-`nil`) symbol then it probably is not an alias in the sense that you care about. See my updated answer for an example `aliased-p` predicate.

Comment: @Drew: your discussion of how `defalias` may be used to setup something else than an alias is confusing/misleading: *all* functions are defined with `defalias` nowadays (e.g. `(defun...)` macroexpands to `(defalias...)`).

Comment: @Stefan: Your reply is confusing (to me). ;-) You don't say what is confusing to you. I didn't say anything about "*using `defalias` to set up something other than an alias*". (?) I only pointed out that the OP is perhaps (probably?) interested only in an alias to a *symbol* and not to a *function*. Maybe your point is only that such a distinction is not useful "nowadays", since all functions are defined with `defalias`? Please consider posting your point/clarification as an answer. (SE is not conducive to discussion.)

Comment: An "alias to a function" is just a normal function (with a name).  While it is technically true, saying that `car` is an alias for the `#<subr car>` primitive is not very useful.  When people talk ab out aliases in Elisp, they always refer to a function whose definition refers to another *name*.

Comment: @Stefan: *When people talk ab...* Yes, which is why I interpreted the OP that way. And yes, an alias to a function "*is a normal function (with a name)*". The point was to tell the OP why my suggestion uses `symbolp`: to exclude functions whose defs do not refer to another name. I think you and I are saying the same thing: `defalias` does not define only what most people think of as an alias (another name for a name). That was my point in adding that info about `defalias`: `defalias` is a confusing name for what it does (it does not necessarily define an alias) - in a way that `fset` is not.

Comment: Right, but the OP did not talk about `defalias`, so there was no need to introduce this confusion.

Comment: @Stefan: You're probably right. I introduced `defalias` to try to help understand the answer I gave. I expect that some readers might automatically think of `defalias` in this context. And the name `defalias` itself introduces a possible confusion: `defalias` does not necessarily create an alias, in the usual sense, but one might also think of the `SYMBOL` arg being an alias for the function (non-symbol `DEFINITION` arg). That is presumably why the macro is called `defalias`, after all. If A and B name object X, instead of A naming B & B naming X, we sometimes do speak of A & B being aliases.

Comment: @Drew. sorry to disrupt you guys in your discussion ;) How can I use the function you showed from the M-x menu? added interactive to allow it to be run from the M-x menu, but can't give it input. When tried it with replacing Fn with the function I want, it showed me that I have no aliasing so your solution is working, I just want to improve it a bit...

Comment: I guess you're asking for a command that does the same thing. I've added that. You need `interactive` to make a function into a command. The `interactive` spec needs to read the function name from the user.

Comment: great, that's exactly what I wanted. aced it Drew!

Answer (score 0):

To go in the other direction from what Drew mentioned, you'd need to scan the entire list of symbols to see if any 'pointed to' a given function symbol, since aliases are one-way relations.

So this function will give you a list of aliases that refer to a given function, using `mapatoms` to iterate over all symbols:

```
(defun get-aliases (fn-symbol)
  "Return a list of aliases for the given function."
  (let ((aliases nil))
    (mapatoms (lambda (sym)
                (if (eq fn-symbol (symbol-function sym))
                    (setq aliases (cons sym aliases)))))
    (nreverse aliases)))
```

e.g.

```
(get-aliases 'cl-caddr) => (caddr cl-third)
```

since `caddr` and `cl-third` 'point to' cl-caddr.

Comment: Sorry, but Drew gave a solution before you did, so I didn't get a chance to check your solution.